# How to prevent outlook.office.com from displaying message source in emails

Tags: asp-classic, iis-8, windows-server

Our club directors are using online.outlook.com as a webmail solution for messaging, and I have noticed something peculiar in that while messages sent to the directors from a mail client like Thunderbird look ok, any emails sent from our online webform look a mess.

For example...

```
Contact = 192.168.0.2 via /contact.asp? 
 ID=7&Subject=Text+format&Name=John&Email=john%40example.com&Message=Click+inside+calendar+to+add+event%2C+move+or+resize+existing+events%2C+select+multiple+days%2C+etc.&g-recaptcha-response=03AGdBq26BbA8M9TkyW521mNLZ6nksqV4EdzajclTJ653GsN4E3opCUKEdrt5hA1orva_V3OF7TghktsatMauhu1Oue6TzMF2xO1wPssI7PCOiwMKcdVGWEprbRkaBxKhyJWo52vFNiuN3cO8xobvydyNcbKyYqPNWn0dZVwhN2Tav4WRQWOp5x1-0lANfpVBtVz8RaxoeAMii5e97tgCbGb06y0VjusA6zYappXDl__E95Zm5Lxm7TakVGhWx-SzRpFsmJJB3aCP1TvsEJIDMn3NN31OZA2SpsvblGywTdAUYQoy7VaWghjgcOoOdCZ2y-oE06l2p5OZ5q1Et_w4SClcrouAjL4rge-i8EIucpYJHKJZtPPoDTT9HPlc4h0T0Hab8frxxeB280O22kPicnYo7lAkU_3TCoj39eYEfyv1s40F5m9opfVF5p36mMRRVcpasp6EXjlwVf8FM6fAgqaMYGd6S6_u1vw&Submit=Submit
-------------------------------------------------------------
Name: John
Email: john@example.com
Subject: Text format
-------------------------------------------------------------

Dear John

Click inside calendar to add event, move or resize existing events, select multiple days, etc.
```

---

Everything above "Name: John" should not be shown and is not shown when the email is sent from Thunderbird.

The code that I used on the mail page looks like...

```
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/config ... /sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/config ... smtpserver") = strMailServer
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/config ... thenticate") = strSmtpAuthenticate
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/config ... ndusername") = strSmptAuthUser
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/config ... ndpassword") = strSmptAuthPass
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/config ... serverport") = 25
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/config ... smtpusessl") = False 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/config ... iontimeout") = 60
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
ObjSendMail.To = strName & " <" & strEmail & ">"
ObjSendMail.Subject = strSubject
ObjSendMail.From = strFromName & " <" & strFromEmail & ">"
ObjSendMail.ReplyTo = strSender & " <" & strSenderEmail & ">"
ObjSendMail.BodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8"
ObjSendMail.TextBody = strEmailBody
ObjSendMail.TextBodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8"
On Error Resume Next
ObjSendMail.Send
Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
```

Charset for the page is set to UTF-8.

[image: What it looks like in Outlook]

Anyone seen this before and know how to prevent it?

Comment: What mail provider are you using to send the emails via CDONTS?

Comment: @692942 the website uses a local mail server. But mail provider is not the problem. The solution below solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and spent days trying to solve it. In the end it was quite simple to fix but difficult to understand how it could be so. But I finally got to send emails that didn't include header data in the email body.

I found that all my pages were using the same include.asp that contained a collection of functions. I solved the problem when I disabled any that were using server variables such as...

```
strCheckIPnumber = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

I didn't want to lose those server variables, so I made their collection conditional so that the webforms for email could exclude them.

Comment: Would never have guessed this, thanks.

Comment: You may find this most useful on any webforms that are sending important info  like login details because I noticed that a lot of our mail was being flagged as spam, making it useless. After removing that unwanted data, the emails are more tidy and now less likely to end up in spam folders.